# Calculating gate to source voltages in h-bridge circuit

Tags: voltage, transistors, voltage-divider, h-bridge

[image]

The circuit shown above is an h-bridge circuit.  It works by letting a microcontroller send a low/high signal on R1 or R4. I've been told to determine all the Gate to source voltages for each of the four MOSFETs when R4 is getting a high signal and when R1 is getting a high signal. I started off by considering the case where R4 got a high signal and R1 low. I was able to calculate the Gate to source voltages of the two transistors Q5 and Q6, but I can't seem to calculate the gate-to-source voltages of Q3 and Q4.

So my question is how would I calculate the gate-source voltages of Q3 and Q4 when R4 receives a high signal and R1 a low signal?

Answer (score 1):

Q3,4 are same but complementary to Q5,6.

Timing depends on Motor L, R values with FET Ciss and collector rise times and PWM rise time for Vgs rise time.

You also need to add a dead-time (depending on transition time) to prevent Vcc to GNd short or "shoot thru" during switch crossover interval. Thus the turn OFF time must be shorter than the turn ON time, so your circuit will fail.

read more http://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/h-bridge_drivers/

Comment: I tried drawing the circuit in a circuit simulator, and it tells me that when there is a high signal on R4 then the Gate-to-source of Q3= -11.9 V and that Q4 is 95.75 mV, but I can't seem to get those values, so how would I calculate them?

Comment: Something is wrong.  Vg3= R7/(R7+R2)*12V = (10k/10k+1k)*12=10.9V,  Vg4 = Vce(sat) @ Ic=12V/1k=12mA = 100mV from datasheet It is a simple voltage divider when Q is OFF.  Note 0V at bottom and (+)12V at top.  No (-)  Check sim V choice and schematic for errors. It is far better for PWM to use Push pull   driver not common emitter.

Comment: I used falstad to draw the circuit. http://tinyurl.com/y8b9wzs5. That is the link to the circuit I have drawn. I don't understand why the gate-to-source voltage wouldn't be negative. Perhaps through the circuit simulation, you can help me understand what is wrong since I myself can't figure out why the schematic should be wrong.